# Salesforce API Integration with External Applications

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, rest-api, integration, apex-webservice

What is the best way to get external Application's data on a regular interval, let's say the application am integrating has 10+ API's, all the API's data have chances of getting added/updated over there at any point, I want salesforce to be up to Date and want those new data to be created as a record. What is the best approach or feasible method to do so

> PS: All API's data are somehow depended on each Other- Trying to display those data's in Lightning App.
>
> Is that the best way to call those API's on constructor when the application is started and upsert the record? or go with the scheduled class

Help me out Guys stuck with this badly

> What's that real-time integration which happens as soon as a record is created or updated.- how it's can be done?
>
> **Is that helps in pulling data from the external application in real-time to
>    salesforce - or salesforce to External Application?**

Comment: best approach : 3-rd party  application produces OData, from the salesfoce side use external objects from salesforce connect feature (paid)

Comment: I just want to Pull changes from other application and store it in Salesforce as soon as changes have happened in the external application. Am just trying for learning purpose and application on my own so paid products won't be good idea